# file validation is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see i am trying to validate file but it doesn't work i am struggling to do this. All form validation is almost done But what i want is if file is not uploaded then it should show alert"your file is not uploaded" and file extension having .jpg,.jpeg,.png and .gif. what is the error in this code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateform()
    {
      var file = document.myform.myfile.value;
      if(file=="")
      {
      alert("select your file");
      document.myform.myfile.focus();
      return false;
      }
     if(file.length)
     {
      var extension = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/i;
      if(!extension.exec(file))
      {
       alert("Please upload file having extensions .jpeg/.jpg/.png/.gif only.");
       file.value = '';
       return false;
      }
     }  
    alert("Form data successfully validated");
    return true;  
    }
</script>  
</head>
<body background="lightpink">
  <form method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="return(validateform())" action="#">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
      <input type="file" id="f" name="myfile"><br><br>
    </div>
  </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "accept" attribute in your `<input>` tag, see it here https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_accept.asp

This will help you limit the file extensions, and you don't even need to use all that RegEx

Comment: Great! It would be even better if you choose to accept this answer.